# Translate Animation seems really jenky/jerky/laggy

Tags: android, animation, lag, translate-animation

Hey guys I'm using a translate animation as seen here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fromXDelta="0" 
     android:toXDelta="0%" 
     android:fromYDelta="-150"
     android:toYDelta="125%p" 
     android:duration="4500"/>
```

Now it works fine, except that it seems to flicker/jerk while animating? Is this standard?

I do have 6 different views being animated at same time, is this cause?

This is how I set the animations:

```
// Create animation for  image
for(x = 0; x < 6; x++){
this.movement[x] = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.animation_test);
this.movement[x].reset();
this.movement[x].setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
this.movement[x].setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
this.movement[x].setStartOffset(x * 1250);
this.movement[x].setAnimationListener(this);    
}

// Create Droplet Layout
for(x = 0; x < 6; x++){
this.mDropletLayout[x] = new LinearLayout(this);
// Randomize        
final long rnd = Math.round(Math.random() * 480);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(                                                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,                                               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.leftMargin = (int) rnd;
this.mLayout[x].setLayoutParams(params);        
}

this.mLayout[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable._1);
this.mLayout[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable._2);
this.mLayout[2].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable._3);
this.mLayout[3].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable._4);
this.mLayout[4].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable._5);
this.mLayout[5].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable._6);

// Attach
for(x = 0; x < 6; x++){
// Attach Animation
this.mLayout[x].startAnimation(this.movement[x]);
// Attach
this.mBackgroundView.addView(this.mLayout[x]);
}
```

Now am I missing something here, cause the animation actually looks like crap to me..?

Answer (score 1):

If multiple animations is a problem, then since you are putting all the child `View`s into a larger enclosing `View`, run the animation on the entire `mBackgroundView` if it has no other children that should be stationary. Otherwise, add an intermediate `View` to `mBackgroundView` containing all the ones that need animation. Then you can just apply the animation to the intermediate `View`.

Edit: I noticed you are making 6 identical animations with `AnimationUtils`. From my understanding you can just use a single one for all views.

Edit 2: Try starting the animation after you do `addView`, instead of before.

Comment: Whole point of having the different animations is that all of the views should be at different stages of the animation at any given time? If I just use one then they all move together? Thanks for the quick reply though, and pointing out I was starting the animation before I even added it to a view.

Comment: Oh, then I guess that you will have to do the individual animations you are doing now, but just use a single `Animation` object.